# Replace line in .sh shell from a python script

Tags: python, replace

I have this code.  I am looking to remove the # in the begining of the line:

```
#/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py
```

and replace it so it reads as a executable line.

```
/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py
```

But its not working.

```
def replace():
    file_path = "/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh"
    find = "#/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py"
    replacement = "/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py"

    with open(file_path) as f:
        s = f.read()
    s = s.replace(find, replacement)
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(s)

replace()
```

these changes did not work:

```
    def replace():
    file_path = "/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh"
    find = "#/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py"
    replacement = replacement = find[1:]

    with open(file_path) as f:
        s = f.read()
    s = s.replace(find, replacement)
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(s)

    replace()
```

from the getweather.sh file.
Need to add a # at the begining to REM it out.

```
# Auto turn on/off dew heater based on auto or manual mode.
python /home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py
```

Comment: It looks like it should work. What is it doing instead?

Comment: To avoid accidentally typing things different, you might want to do: `replacement = find[1:]`.

Comment: Just does not perform the add of the #   NO ERRORS   your saying replace replacement = "/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py"   with replacemnt - find [1]  ?    sorry new to coding

Comment: The only explanation is that the file doesn't actually contain the line you're replacing.

Comment: Please paste the script into the question.

Comment: That is the script in the question.   It's the last few lines in a python script, that opens a .sh file to change that line'

Comment: I meant paste the contents of `getweather.sh` so we can see what you're trying to replace.

Comment: Well, your code is removing a `#`, not adding one.

Comment: Thats what I want to remove the #.    There is another file I have to add to so it puts it back.

Comment: cp /home/pi/dew-heater/dewheater_overlay.txt /home/pi/allsky/tmp/extra

#!/bin/sh
#python /home/pi/dew-heater/forecast.py

Answer (score 0):

this works

```
with open('/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh', 'r') as fp:
    data = fp.read()
    typos = data.replace('/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py', '#/home/pi/dew-heater/get-temp.py')
with open('/home/pi/dew-heater/getweather.sh', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(typos)
```